# put the code into the template.php file?

Tags: theming

```
<div class="meta">
  <?php 
    echo  $submitted;
    $common = $content['body']['#object']->field_fenlei['zh-hans'];
    foreach($common as $vocab){
      echo  l($vocab['taxonomy_term']->name,$vocab['taxonomy_term']->uri['path']);
    } 
  ?>
</div>
```

This code is the one I wrote for node.tpl.php, and it's too bad. Is there a way to put the code into the template.php file? How do I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's fine to put code in template.php, but do not print or echo there. All print or echo code should be in template files (.tpl.php). If you need to prepare variables for output in a template file, alter a preprocess function (eg. THEMENAME_preprocess_page if you need them in page.tpl.php), add your variables to the $variables array (eg. `$variables['greeting'] = 'Hello!';` and print those variables in the template file (`print $greeting;`).

So for this example it would be something like:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $common = $variables['content']['body']['#object']->field_fenlei['zh-hans'];
  $term_links = '';
  foreach($common as $vocab){
    $term_links .= l($vocab['taxonomy_term']->name,$vocab['taxonomy_term']->uri['path']);
  } 
  $variables['fenlei_term_links'] = $term_links;
}
```

Now you can access the output with the variable $fenlei_term_links in your node.tpl.php:

```
<?php print $fenlei_term_links; ?>
```

In general you might want to use something like http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_links or http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_items

Comment: i don't know how to put this part 
             foreach($common as $vocab){
            echo  l($vocab['taxonomy_term']->name,$vocab['taxonomy_term']->uri['path']);
        }  in template.php?

Comment: See the code example above that was added to my post. (Credits for the code example go to Daniel Wehner who initially edited my post. I only made small improvements and published it.)

Answer (score 1):

In template.php:

```
function THEME_preprocess_node($vars) {
  $node =& $vars['node'];
  if (!empty($content['body']['#object']->field_fenlei['zh-hans']) {
    foreach($content['body']['#object']->field_fenlei['zh-hans'] as $vocab){
      $vars['common'][] = l($vocab['taxonomy_term']->name, $vocab['taxonomy_term']->uri['path']);
    }
  }
}
```

In node.tpl.php:

```
<div class="meta"><?php
  print $submitted;
  print implode('', is_array($common) ? $common : array());
?></div>
```

Comment: Personally, I would move the implode() and empty() logic into template.php as well, so you only have to print out the variable in your template.

Comment: Putting the implode() logic in the template.php means that if the theme (or a subtheme) has to be updated to incldue a separator between the links, the function preprocess has to be updated (or in the case of a subtheme, the value of $common recomputed). The empty() is only a safeguard to avoid error when $common is undefined in the .tpl.php and should actually be is_array().

Comment: I understand that. Regarding control over the separator, I wouldn't mind to edit the preprocess function for that, but I can see why you want to have it the tpl.php. Regarding the is_array check, I would prefer to initialize $common as empty array in the preprocess function so you can safely `implode('', $common)` in the template.